# Drools KieSession causes memory leak

Tags: drools

I am using Drools 6.3.0.Final to run 100 rules in different KieSessions, one rule per session, and the engine works in STREAM mode. I am using the annotation @Expires at the code level to define the life-time of the Pojo I am pushing in the sessions.

The problem is that after running the application for few hours, I noticed a memory leak, and by analyzing the heap dump I can see millions of Pojos referenced from Drool Sessions. Which means, the Pojos are not removed from the sessions.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Here is my Pojo:

```
@Role(Role.Type.EVENT)
@Expires("10s")
public class DataStreamRecord {
......
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be fixed using Drools 6.5.0-Final which has conflicts with EAP 6.2 as explained here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1165

I fixed this issue by adding the following line to the rule just before passing it to Drools :

```html
declare DataStreamRecord @role( event ) @expires( 10s ) end
```

Here is an example :

```html
 String drl = "package org.test.common.beans;\r\n"+
 "rule my_rule \r\n"+ 
 "when\r\n"+ 
 "$streamRecord:DataStreamRecord()\r\n"+
 "then\r\n"+ 
  "System.out.println(\"Received data:\" + $streamRecord);\r\n"+
  "end"+
  " declare DataStreamRecord @role( event ) @expires( 10s ) end  ";        

 KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
 KieFileSystem kfs =
 ks.newKieFileSystem().write(ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(drl.getBytes())
```

Comment: I dont think it works with Declaration as above in the drl files.

declare Fact
@role( event )
@expires(value = 60s)
end
I tried this, after 60 seconds also, I can see the instances of Fact exist in the Drools working memory using MAT tool. Ideally, this should have removed by Drools engine after 60s related to its time of insertion.

Any help ?